# How to match a pattern and replace all files in a directory using salt states?

Tags: salt-stack

Salt stack state to recursively loop over a directory

Added single and multiple quotes, that didn't help. I don't wish to specify each file for a file replace. I want to loop all files under dir for replace.

```
{% for file in "/path/{{ to }}/dir" %}
  {{ file }}:
    file.replace:
      - name: {{ file }}
      - pattern: /from/
      - repl: /{{ to }}/
      - backup: False
{% endfor %}
```

I tried single quotes and multiple quotes, but see the error:

```
":"ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code
d01xyz011:
Data failed to compile:
----------
Rendering SLS 'base:projects.xyz.p-ser' failed: Jinja syntax error: unexpected '/'; line 140
```

Can we specify a directory in FOR Loop where we have multiple files to be replaced? Is there additional code that I am missing in the above FOR Loop? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a files list and then do a for loop on it, like

```
{% set file_list = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] %}
{% for f in file_list %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

But I don't think `{% for file in "/path/{{ to }}/dir" %}` will do what you think it does: it won't create a list of files in the directory, you will need to create this list elsewhere or in another way and then give it to your for loop in Jinja.